# Why are there two kinds of formula for Probability Generating Function?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

In [this link](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics100B/stat100b_mgf.pdf):

[image]

**On the other hand**, [in this link](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~fewster/325/notes/325book.pdf):

[image]

So, how are these two equations **same**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link gives the formula for **moment** generating function. $M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$

The second link gives the formula for **probability** generating function for **discrete** random variable. $G_X(s)=E[s^X]$

They are not the same.